# Disable missing javadoc comments in checkstye.xml

Tags: java, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I am trying to disable "missing javadoc comments" error in my checkstyle.xml in a Maven project.
I tried to add the following module but it didn't work:

```
<!-- No need for Javadoc -->
    <module name="JavadocType">
        <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
        <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocVariable">
        <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    </module>
```

Is there any particular module I can add to disable all javadoc comments check or any kind of changes I can make to a Maven dependency?

Comment: My understanding is that you actually have to remove the checks from the list. Can you?

Comment: @Boris I tried to, it didn't work for me though. After all the javadoc-related modules were removed, I tried to build my project in Maven and I still got the very same error message.

Comment: It can't be possible! Can you double check that the file you are modifying is actually the file which is being used by checkstyle. If you use maven than it should be configured like, for example, <configLocation>/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml</configLocation>

Comment: @Boris I do have  <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>.

Comment: Strange. I use google_checks.xml only without "JavadocMethod" module and Checkstyle doesn't complain. Here is my modified config file: https://bitbucket.org/borisredkin/java-header-updater/src/ff158ec6a348a065e11bc820acf9712a527d5916/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default And here is the original file: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

Comment: @Boris thanks, I have also tried to use checkstyle-suppression.xml, however it didn't help

Comment: Removing the modules is the way to go, like @Boris said. If this doesn't do it for you, you have modified the wrong file, or there's a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there were some mismatches in Checkstyle releases and the Maven Checkstyle plugin. There is a way the problem with Checkstyle can be solved:
 MVN plugin with Checkstyle latest version provided (so far it was 8.5):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

As you can see, it uses an older version of Checkstyle. However, you need to use an older plugin in your IDE as well.